# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and trying to map an already created Table in oracle db. in Below given code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

String hql = "FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo where rownum<20";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

List itr = query.list();
session.getTransaction().commit();

for (Iterator iterator = itr.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
System.out.println("[" + iterator.next() + "]");
}
```

When I run this code. It First gives this Exception:

```
Apr 26, 2016 8:10:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: sdp.crbt_subscriber_master
Hibernate: create table sdp.crbt_subscriber_master (MSISDN varchar2(255) not null, STATUS varchar2(255), DATE_REGISTERED date, PLAN_INDICATOR number(10,0), RBT_CODE number(10,0), PASSWORD varchar2(255), TPIN varchar2(255), FREE_EVENTS_USED number(10,0), BLACK_LISTED number(10,0), LANGUAGE number(10,0), DEFAULT_GROUP_SETTING varchar2(255), DEFAULT_SINGLE_SETTING varchar2(255), DATE_SETTING_VALIDITY number(10,0), IMSI varchar2(255), LAST_CHARGED date, IS_MONTHLY_CHARGEABLE varchar2(255), CORP_ID number(10,0), SUB_TYPE varchar2(255), RENEW_MODE number(10,0), EXPIRY_DATE date, ACTIVE_FEATURES number(10,0), IN_USE_RBT number(10,0), UPDATE_TIME date, CORP_EXPIRY date, primary key (MSISDN))
Apr 26, 2016 8:10:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [create table sdp.crbt_subscriber_master (MSISDN varchar2(255) not null, STATUS varchar2(255), DATE_REGISTERED date, PLAN_INDICATOR number(10,0), RBT_CODE number(10,0), PASSWORD varchar2(255), TPIN varchar2(255), FREE_EVENTS_USED number(10,0), BLACK_LISTED number(10,0), LANGUAGE number(10,0), DEFAULT_GROUP_SETTING varchar2(255), DEFAULT_SINGLE_SETTING varchar2(255), DATE_SETTING_VALIDITY number(10,0), IMSI varchar2(255), LAST_CHARGED date, IS_MONTHLY_CHARGEABLE varchar2(255), CORP_ID number(10,0), SUB_TYPE varchar2(255), RENEW_MODE number(10,0), EXPIRY_DATE date, ACTIVE_FEATURES number(10,0), IN_USE_RBT number(10,0), UPDATE_TIME date, CORP_EXPIRY date, primary key (MSISDN))]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [create table sdp.crbt_subscriber_master (MSISDN varchar2(255) not null, STATUS varchar2(255), DATE_REGISTERED date, PLAN_INDICATOR number(10,0), RBT_CODE number(10,0), PASSWORD varchar2(255), TPIN varchar2(255), FREE_EVENTS_USED number(10,0), BLACK_LISTED number(10,0), LANGUAGE number(10,0), DEFAULT_GROUP_SETTING varchar2(255), DEFAULT_SINGLE_SETTING varchar2(255), DATE_SETTING_VALIDITY number(10,0), IMSI varchar2(255), LAST_CHARGED date, IS_MONTHLY_CHARGEABLE varchar2(255), CORP_ID number(10,0), SUB_TYPE varchar2(255), RENEW_MODE number(10,0), EXPIRY_DATE date, ACTIVE_FEATURES number(10,0), IN_USE_RBT number(10,0), UPDATE_TIME date, CORP_EXPIRY date, primary key (MSISDN))]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.telemune.demoHibernate.QueryTester.(QueryTester.java:17)
    at com.telemune.demoHibernate.QueryTester.main(QueryTester.java:21)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:961)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1190)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1726)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1696)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 14 more

Apr 26, 2016 8:10:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: sdp.crbt_subscriber_master
Apr 26, 2016 8:10:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: sdp.crbt_subscriber_master
```

and then show the required result successfully.
But I want to know the reason for the Exception. Asking for help. I only know some things about hibenate, sorry if its a silly question.

`sdp` is the name of data base. and this is my mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">; 
<hibernate-mapping> 
<class name="com.telemune.demoPojo.CrbtSubMasterDemo" 
table="sdp.crbt_subscriber_master"> 
<id column="MSISDN" name="mobile" type="java.lang.String">
<generator class="native"/></id> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you specify a schema name with a table name here

```
<class name="com.telemune.demoPojo.CrbtSubMasterDemo" 
  table="sdp.crbt_subscriber_master">
```

Hibernate considers `sdp.crbt_subscriber_master` as a table name.

But when Hibernate tries to execute `create table sdp.crbt_subscriber_master()` Oracle considers `sdp` as a schema name and `crbt_subscriber_master` as a table name.

Don't know exactly how to specify a schema name for a mapping but you can try as described here

[Chapter 5. Basic O/R Mapping: mapping-declaration-class](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class)

```
<class name="com.telemune.demoPojo.CrbtSubMasterDemo" 
  schema="sdp" table="crbt_subscriber_master">
```

Comment: Yeah you may be right but how should I resolve it, so that it doesn't give the Exception?

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj Please, see a mapping example :)

Comment: that was a simpler one by the way ... thankyou sir @v.ladynev. Please sir can you expalin the above fact that when I replace update by none it solved the Exception Problem. How? Will it work for all other queries??

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj `update = none` means that Hibernate doesn't update a database schema while process a mapping (looks like there is not a `none` value, you can simply comment or remove `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` ). It is not any Exception, because of Hibernate doesn't try to create tables.

Comment: @ v.ladynev mr.  v.ladynev how can I ask my further question on hibernate directly to you?

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj It will be better, if you ask here on SO. There are a lot of people here who know Hibernate very well. And I am always here :)

Answer (score 0):

Here table name is case sensitive. There is a mismatch.

```
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: sdp.crbt_subscriber_master
```

Database is trying to get `crbt_subscriber_master` but you have given

```
String hql = "FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo where rownum
```

---

### Your issue is here:

There is another problem also. You have missed to add declaring hql perfectly.

**Use this code**

```
String hql = "FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo where rownum";
```

instead of

```
String hql = "FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo where rownum
```

You can also go through this tutorial: [ORA-00955: name is already being used by existing object tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00955_name_already_used_by_existing_object.htm)

---

### UPDATE:

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto Automatically validates or exports schema DDL
>   to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop,
>   the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed
>   explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

So the list of possible options are,

**validate**: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.

**update**: update the schema.

**create**: creates the schema, destroying previous data.

**create-drop**: drop the schema at the end of the session.

So, As it is already created the data table. Then if you **remove this property from your configuration, then it will be solved.**

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

But you can give a try. This will also solve the issue.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

or

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
```

Sometimes empty string' is much more better than 'none'. To use 'none', you will receive `warning message: org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none`

Comment: the line I added was : **String hql = "FROM CrbtSubMasterDemo where rownum<20";** I don't know why it isn't show the whole line.... And this is trying to  get _crbt_subscriber_master_ because this is the name of the mapped table with the **CrbtSubMasterDemo** pojo class @SkyWalker

Comment: sdp is the name of data base. and this is my mapping: **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.telemune.demoPojo.CrbtSubMasterDemo" table="sdp.crbt_subscriber_master">
        <id column="MSISDN" name="mobile" type="java.lang.String"><generator class="native"/></id>


</hibernate-mapping>**

Comment: Actually you have the problem that the table is already exists which one is called again to create. So you have to check it that if the table exists then drop it and then try to create it.

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj To resolve ORA-00955, make sure to give the database object an unmatched name.  You can also drop or modify the existing object so that it can be reused, without being identical syntax.

Comment: No, I cannot Drop the table....It contains huge amount of data. I am using **<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>**.

Comment: And yes, As I said I need to fetch data from an **Already Existing Table**. This will not be the resolution to the problem I think.

Comment: Why this is called create table sdp.crbt_subscriber_master more times is the issue for you.

Comment: Yeah, Exactly. 1. Why is it calling create Table while I am using Update + the table in sdp db already exists? 2. If it could not find the existing table how is it showing the desired result after giving this exception? 3. If it can find the existing table (as it is showing the desired result) why is it giving the table not exist and calling create?

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj I have updated the answer. Please have a try and let me know.

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj Please, don't edit an answer with comments :)

Comment: when I tried to use _validate_ instead of _update_ **INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: sdp.crbt_subscriber_master
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [sdp.crbt_subscriber_master]
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.performValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:100)
 at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)**

Comment: Yeah **_none_** solved it but will it work on the other query like **Insert**,**update**,**Delete**?